Is the 'Allowed Memory Size Exhausted' Error Related to the 'MaxAttemptsExceededException' in Laravel Queues?
We’ve been encountering the following error on our Laravel project:
Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 124213718 Bytes Exhausted.
Additionally, our queue workers are logging errors in the failed_jobs table, specifically:
Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException.
My question is: Are these two errors correlated? Could the memory exhaustion be a contributing factor to the MaxAttemptsExceededException?
On the server, our /etc/php.ini file currently has memory_limit = 512M. We have sufficient resources to increase this to 2G. Would raising the memory limit potentially resolve or alleviate these issues?
To give some context.  Our cron job is hitting over 4000 RDS instances.  One of the instances is causing this error to appear in failed_jobs table.
One of the possible solutions tried:  In the superivsor.d directory in the queueworker.ini file - I've increased the timeout to 300 as I saw that's a common solution but it still didn't work.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!
queueworker.ini file
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/my-app/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --timeout=300
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=admin
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/my-app/storage/logs/worker.log
startsecs=0


"Could the memory exhaustion be a contributing factor to the MaxAttemptsExceededException?" - yes, a fatal error will stop the execution of the job, and this job will be retried until it exceeds it's max attempt, at that point a MaxAttemptsExceededException will be thrown, and the job will be moved to failed_jobs

you need to fix your memory leak in your job, try setting the max amount of jobs a worker can process before restarting, or check your code for things to optimize. You should not need more than 128mb to process a single job, let alone 512mb or 2gb
